# Как создать разные стили графиков QtCharts?

Tags: c++, qt

Начал изучать QtCharts, наткнулся на проблему с изменением стилей графиков. При большом количестве цвета начинают повторяться. Хотелось бы изменить стили (линия с точкой, с пробелом, с квадратом, с треугольником и т.д.).

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-chartthemes-example.html

Comment: Нужны именно разные стили линий (прерывистая, прерывистая с точкой и т.д.)

Comment: Там есть всякие методы типа setPen, setBrush и так далее. Пробуйте, экспериментируйте https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxyseries.html